# Form input fields validation via jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, jquery-plugins

I want to validate my form input fields on button click in jQuery. But I don't want to use client side validation. How can I add PHP server-side validation on button click?

I am using modal box for form.

I know it is a beginner's level question, but currently I am unable to figure it out because of my low expertise.

Comment: Your statements are contradictory. Validating on button click in jQuery, but not using client side?

Comment: *"but i don't want to use client side validation"* - Then you don't want to use JavaScript for validation.  In your PHP code where you process the form submit, perform your validation logic.  If the validation fails, I suspect you'd either return an error or direct the user in some way.  But it's really up to you what you want to do at that point.  It's not really clear what you've tried or where you're stuck.

Comment: let makes it more clear, is there anyway that i can use both side validations, client side to make form pretty and server side to make it secure? @El_Vanja

Comment: @AliAkbar: Of course you can.  It's very common to have both those levels of validation for exactly that reason, a balance of UX and security.  Have you tried something that isn't working in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can validate using `PHP` and it's not a big deal. I'll provide a simple example here to pass the form data to PHP for validation.

```php
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submitForm']) )
{
    $userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $userAge = $_POST['userAge'];
    
    if ($userAge > 21)
    {
      echo "Hey " + userName;
    }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action=""> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="userName">
    Age: <input type="number" name="userAge">
    <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Validate"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you wish to pass the data to another page to validate, just give the file name in `action` attribute, like `action="Your_PHP_File.php"` and validate separately. *Just a tip*: If you wish to redirect on success (heavily used):

```php
header("Location: Your_URL_Here");
```

Anyways, this is not a better user experience. You must use client side validation using JavaScript/any JavaScript framework, and use language like PHP only to communicate with the server, such as storing the data in the database, retrieving data from the database.

Comment: thanks @Deepak. let me try this. I hope it will work for me.